# General timeout exception in Selenium WebDriver during Navigate().GotoUrl()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I have a WinForms app, that executes several chromdrivers (20-30) using Selenium.I get some strange error, that I can't debug:

```
timeout
(Session info: headless chrome=69.0.3497.100)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),
    platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)  
    Stacktrace:     
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)    
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

Just "timeout" and nothing else, huh?! Tried to set various timeouts using:

```
_browser = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(360));
_browser.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
_browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
_browser.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
```

but nothing helps :-( 
Does anyone know how to deal with it? Maybe it is related to the fact, that there are many chromedrivers that run in parallel?

Update 1: Tried to set options.`PageLoadStrategy` to `None` - no timeouts, but wrong html for dynamic pages :( `PageLoadStrategy.Eager` also doesn't work, says "cannot parse capability, unsupported".

Comment: does your browser gets loaded or not ?

Comment: @AshishKamble - yep, the process chrome.exe starts in headless mode